# cambiar imagen por fila en listview vb6

Tags: vb6

Estoy modificando una aplicación de mi trabajo. Está hecha en VB6 , la idea es que recibo un OK o un error por medio de un winsock, y yo debo volcar ese estado a una fila de un listview.

He logrado casi que funcione, al recibir , busco en las filas del listview si el id o nombre del registro existe, y de ser asi solo modifico si es Ok o Tipo de Error, pero no logro reflejar ese estado cambiando la imagen de la primer columna.

Tengo el listview1 enlazado a un imagelist1, donde inserté 2 imágenes:

- la 1era es index 1 key estado_ok
- la segunda index 2 estado_err

necesito poder cambiar el icono en tiempo de ejecución.
Les paso el código involucrado:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim ch As ColumnHeader

    With ListView1
        .ColumnHeaders.Clear
        .ListItems.Clear
        .View = lvwReport
        .SmallIcons = ImageList1
        .SortKey = 0
        .SortOrder = lvwAscending
        .Sorted = True
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "           Equipo", 1700)
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "Estado", 1700)
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "Fecha reporte", 2300, lvwColumnCenter)
        Set ch = .ColumnHeaders.Add(, , "Tickets", 1074, lvwColumnCenter)
    End With

    Label1 = Winsock1.LocalIP
'    ReDim acumulado(0)


    'Cargo parámetros winsock y oculto el form1
     Call Carga_Inicial

    'Habilito el systray oculto y ok
     Call Carga_Ok(1)

End Sub
```

Y acá es donde debería cambiar el icono, y todo lo que probé me da error

```vb
    If cadena(1) <> "Impresora Ok !" Then  
        ListView1.SmallIcon = ImageList1.ListImages.Item(1)
        Else
        ListView1.SmallIcon = ImageList1.ListImages.Item(2)
    End If
```

Ya sé que está muy mal, pero no le encuentro la vuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código en el que se debe cambiar el ícono del elemento, está tratando de modificar la referencia del control y no la propiedad del elemento.

El código debe determinar el índice del elemento del control `ListView` que se debe modificar y luego cambiar la propiedad `SmallIcon` del elemento:

```vb
Dim nElemento as Integer

'Obtener índice del elemento a modificar de alguna forma
'Asumiendo que se desea cambiar el ícono del primer elemento de la lista
nElemento = 1

If cadena(1) <> "Impresora Ok !" Then  
    ListView1.ListItems(nElemento).SmallIcon = 1 'o "estado_ok"
Else
    ListView1.ListItems(nElemento).SmallIcon = "estado_err" 'o 2
End If
```

A las propiedades `Icon` y `SmallIcon` de los objetos `ListItem` se les puede asignar el índice correspondiente en el control `ImageList` asociado a las propiedades `Icons` y `SmallIcons` respectivamente del control `ListView` al que pertenecen.  El índice puede ser el número de la posición de la imagen en el control `ImageList` de acuerdo a como se agregaron las imágenes iniciando con 1; o puede ser el valor de la propiedad `Key` asociado a la imagen en el control `ImageList`.

Ok las rutinas que agregan y modifican :

```vb
Private Sub agregar_item(cadena1 As String)
Dim subelemento As ListItem
Dim n As Integer
Dim aSubItems() As String

    aSubItems = Split(cadena1, ",")

    If aSubItems(3) = "TERMINAL1" Then aSubItems(3) = "TERMINAL 1"
    If aSubItems(1) = "AUTOOK" Then aSubItems(1) = "Impresora Ok !"
    If aSubItems(1) = "AUTOERROR" Then aSubItems(1) = "Fuera de Servicio !"
    If aSubItems(1) = "AUTOPAPEL" Then aSubItems(1) = "Cambiar Papel !"

    Set subelemento = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , aSubItems(3), , 1)
        subelemento.SubItems(1) = aSubItems(1)
        subelemento.SubItems(2) = aSubItems(4)
        subelemento.SubItems(3) = aSubItems(2)

    ListView1.SortKey = 0
    ListView1.SortOrder = lvwAscending
    ListView1.Sorted = True
    Erase aSubItems
End Sub

Private Function modificar_lv(nom_terminal2 As String) As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim cad_item As String

    For i = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count
        cad_item = ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).Text
'            If cad_item = nom_terminal2 Then ListView1.ListItems.Remove (i): MsgBox ("Item Removido!")
            If cad_item = nom_terminal2 Then
                ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(1) = mensaje_error
                ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(2) = mensaje_fechayhora
                ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3) = mensaje_cuenta
                modificar_lv = True
                Exit Function
            End If
    Next i

        ListView1.SortKey = 0
        ListView1.SortOrder = lvwAscending
        ListView1.Sorted = True

i = 0
cad_item = ""

End Function
```

Comment: Gracias ! Disculpa que le pongo ganas pero me falta un poco ..Mi duda es como puedo acceder a la propiedad index de cada fila , o sea, tengas 2 rutinas , 1 para agregar fila y otra para modificar ..

Tratare´de agregarlas a la pregunta , gracias

Comment: Hola OK, esto me dio una idea de como resolver, muchas gracias ! ya está funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Los Index de los Items en ImageList1 Empiezan Por 0 y cuando llega al 2 te salta el error...

```
If cadena(1) <> "Impresora Ok !" Then  
    ListView1.SmallIcon = ImageList1.ListImages.Item(0)
Else
    ListView1.SmallIcon = ImageList1.ListImages.Item(1)
End If
```